# Test.Bus is null when unit testing saga in NServiceBus

Tags: nservicebus

I want to inject the `IBus` that is used when doing unit testing in NServiceBus into the sagas and handler I am testing, but the `Test.Bus` is `null`. How do I get access to the `IBus` so I can inject into my handlers and sagas. I really don't like to have public properties for those kind of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer it myself since I found it myself. The problem was that I was overriding the `IBus` property which I inherited from the `Saga<>`. So if you have a saga like this

```
public void SomeSaga : Saga<SomeData>
{
    private IBus _bus;
    public SomeSaga(..., IBus bus)
    {
        _bus = bus;
    }

    public void Handle(SomeMessage message)
    {
        _bus.Publish(something);
    }
}
```

**Change it to:**

```
public void SomeSaga : Saga<SomeData>
{
    public SomeSaga(...)
    {
    }

    public void Handle(SomeMessage message)
    {
        Bus.Publish(something);
    }
}
```

Comment: This can also happen if you forget to call Test.Initialize() to initialize the testing framework.

Comment: @DavidBoike great extra comment :)